# How come islice is only printing []?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scripting

The following function is supposed to print 200 lines but instead is only printing "[]". I am not entirely sure where I am going wrong here and would like a fresh pair of eyes to help me out.

Thank you!

```
def main():
from itertools import islice
userfile = raw_input("Please enter the file you wish to open\n(must be in this directory): ")
file1 = open(userfile, "r+")
jcardtop = file1.read(221);
#print jcardtop
n = 200
while True:
    next_n_lines = list(islice(file1,n))
    if not next_n_lines:
        break
print next_n_lines
```

Comment: Are you sure that `file1` has more lines after you've read the first 221 bytes?

Comment: @IanAuld: You really shouldn't edit a post to fix indentation errors when the problem is almost certainly caused by indentation…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code actually looks like what you posted:

```
while True:
    next_n_lines = list(islice(file1,n))
    if not next_n_lines:
        break
print next_n_lines
```

… then the problem is that you don't `print` anything until the loop is done, meaning you only print the very last slice, which is, by definition, empty.

If your code *doesn't* look like that in your text editor, it may *still* look like that to Python, because you may be mixing tabs and spaces. Try using a better text editor—almost anything but Notepad or TextEdit will have an option to convert tabs to spaces, or to show tabs visibly. Or run your script with Python's `-tt` flag.